# Double hard drive, double OS windows+ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I bought an SSD for my laptop and I moved the old one on the optical drive bay. I installed windows on my SSD **and then** installed **ubuntu** on the old one (sdb). 
I installed Ubuntu using manual partitioning and installed grub on the windows hard drive (sda) and now I'm not able to boot windows anymore nor to find it using grub-update.

os-prober gives me only ubuntu:

```
sudo os-prober /dev/sdb1:Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (14.04):Ubuntu:linux
```

Windows is on sda.

How to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank for your time but I have the opposite problem and a two hard drives case.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The solution is the same: to repair the boot loader and its configuration. If it doesn't help, please include a link to the Boot-Repair log in your question as it contains most of the necessary problems to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reinstalling windows 10 MBR on the the first hard drive using a usb drive. The I installed grub on the second hard drive (where Ubuntu is) and I put it as first in the boot order. Grub is now able to recognize the window partition and everything works fine.